# Using an array in google sheets

Tags: arrays

I'm trying to find a solution to a problem in Google sheets

Is it possible to do what I'm attempting with the formula below

=ArrayFormula(XLOOKUP(A71,$B$26:$B$45&$C$26:$C$45&$D$26:$D$45&$E$26:$E$45&$F$26:$F$45&$G$26:$G$45&$H$26:$H$45,$A$26:$A$45,"Not found",0,1))

Basically, I have a table with job numbers in the range B26:H45 (not all cells are populated) with the engineers names in the range A26:A45 (all cells are populated).

In A71 I have the job number,in B71 I have the formula above but I have been trying for ages to get this to work without any luck.

Any help would be appreciated

cheers

Paul

I have tried multiple methods of doing this without any luck

Comment: XLOOKUP may not be the best function to use in this specific case. Instead, you can achieve your goal with VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH combination.

Comment: many thanks for your reply, I'm still having problems with this, I'll try it with vlookup as you suggest

Comment: Do you want to find the engineer's name based on the job number in cell A71?

Comment: Hi, yes that is what I'm attempting to do. I've been scratching my head with this for a couple of days now on and off and I'm still unable to do it.

Comment: Ok I will share a formula. Please try it and let me know.

Answer (score -1):

You want to find the engineer's name based on the job number in cell A71, you can use the following formula in cell B71:

```
=INDEX($A$26:$A$45, MATCH(A71, $B$26:$B$45&$C$26:$C$45&$D$26:$D$45&$E$26:$E$45&$F$26:$F$45&$G$26:$G$45&$H$26:$H$45, 0))
```

Can u try and let me know?
If error continue,  give me more detail please.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for you reply. I did exactly the same as you above when you first replied, I have tested it and have found the the same issue. If I shorten the formula to

Comment: =INDEX($A$26:$A$45, MATCH(A71, $B$26:$B$45&$C$26:$C$45&$D$26:$D$45&$E$26:$E$45, 0))

Comment: it works, as the first match is in column E, if i use the whole formula it gives #N/A no match found

Comment: please excuse me not using code tags, this is the first time i have posted to Stack Overflow and cant quite figure out how to use it yet (sorry)

Comment: interestingly, I copied the sheet into excel and had exactly the same problem, it only worked when I removed anything after the first match